# NumPy implementation of the Nearest Neighbor classification algorithm classifies everything the exact same way

Tags: c#, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, knn

My assignment is to use a K-Nearest Neighbor algorithm to determine what kind of flower something is based on various features of it (e.g. stem length, petal length, etc.) using NumPy. (For the record, I've worked with Python in the past, although it's not my "best" language; however, I'm completely new to NumPy).

Both my training and my testing data are in CSVs that look like this:

```
4.6,3.6,1.0,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.3,1.7,0.5,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.4,1.9,0.2,Iris-setosa
7.0,3.2,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor
6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.3,4.0,1.3,Iris-versicolor
```

I know how to do the basic algorithm. Here's the C# I created for it:

```
namespace Project_3_Prototype
{
    public class FourD
    {
        public double f1, f2, f3, f4;

        public string name;

        public static double Distance(FourD a, FourD b)
        {
            double squared = Math.Pow(a.f1 - b.f1, 2) + Math.Pow(a.f2 - b.f2, 2) + Math.Pow(a.f3 - b.f3, 2) + Math.Pow(a.f4 - b.f4, 2);

            return Math.Sqrt(squared);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<FourD> distances = new List<FourD>();

            using (var parser = new TextFieldParser("iris-training-data.csv"))
            {
                parser.SetDelimiters(",");

                while (!parser.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

                    var curr = new FourD
                    {
                        f1 = double.Parse(fields[0]),
                        f2 = double.Parse(fields[1]),
                        f3 = double.Parse(fields[2]),
                        f4 = double.Parse(fields[3]),
                        name = fields[4]
                    };

                    distances.Add(curr);
                }
            }

            double correct = 0, total = 0;

            using (var parser = new TextFieldParser("iris-testing-data.csv"))
            {
                parser.SetDelimiters(",");

                int i = 1;

                while (!parser.EndOfData)
                {
                    total++;
                    string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

                    var curr = new FourD
                    {
                        f1 = double.Parse(fields[0]),
                        f2 = double.Parse(fields[1]),
                        f3 = double.Parse(fields[2]),
                        f4 = double.Parse(fields[3]),
                        name = fields[4]
                    };

                    FourD min = distances[0];

                    foreach (FourD comp in distances)
                    {
                        if (FourD.Distance(comp, curr) < FourD.Distance(min, curr))
                        {
                            min = comp;
                        }
                    }

                    if (min.name == curr.name)
                    {
                        correct++;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", i, curr.name, min.name));

                    i++;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Accuracy: " + correct / total);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is working exactly as expected, with the following output:

```
# The format is Number,Correct label,Predicted Label
1,Iris-setosa,Iris-setosa
2,Iris-setosa,Iris-setosa
3,Iris-setosa,Iris-setosa
4,Iris-setosa,Iris-setosa
5,Iris-setosa,Iris-setosa
6,Iris-setosa,Iris-setosa
7,Iris-setosa,Iris-setosa
8,Iris-setosa,Iris-setosa
9,Iris-setosa,Iris-setosa
10,Iris-setosa,Iris-setosa
11,Iris-setosa,Iris-setosa
12,Iris-setosa,Iris-setosa
...

Accuracy: 0.946666666666667
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in NumPy. However, the assignment does not permit me to use `for` loops, only vectorized functions.

So, basically what I want to do is: for every row in the testing data, get the index of the row in the training data that's closest to it (i.e. has the minimum Euclidean distance).

Here's what I tried in Python:

```
import numpy as np

def main():    
    # Split each line of the CSV into a list of attributes and labels
    data = [x.split(',') for x in open("iris-training-data.csv")]

    # The last item is the label
    labels = np.array([x[-1].rstrip() for x in data])

    # Convert the first 3 items to a 2D array of floats
    floats = np.array([x[0:3] for x in data]).astype(float)

    classifyTrainingExamples(labels, floats)

def classifyTrainingExamples(labels, floats):
    # We're basically doing the same thing to the testing data that we did to the training data
    testingData = [x.split(',') for x in open("iris-testing-data.csv")]

    testingLabels = np.array([x[-1].rstrip() for x in testingData])

    testingFloats = np.array([x[0:3] for x in testingData]).astype(float)

    res = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: closest(floats, x), 1, testingFloats)

    correct = 0

    for number, index in enumerate(res):    
        if labels[index] == testingLabels[number]:
            correct += 1

        print("{},{},{}".format(number + 1, testingLabels[number], labels[index]))

        number += 1

    print(correct / len(list(res)))

def closest(otherArray, item):
    res = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: distance(x, item), 1, otherArray)

    i = np.argmin(res)

    return i

# Get the Euclidean distance between two "flat" lists (i.e. one particular row
def distance(a, b):
    # Subtract one from the other elementwise, then raise each one to the power of 2
    lst = (a - b) ** 2

    # Sum all of the elements together, and take the square root
    result = np.sqrt(lst.sum())

    return result

main()
```

Unfortunately, the output looks like

```
1,Iris-setosa,Iris-setosa
2,Iris-setosa,Iris-setosa
3,Iris-setosa,Iris-setosa
4,Iris-setosa,Iris-setosa
....
74,Iris-setosa,Iris-setosa
75,Iris-setosa,Iris-setosa
0.93333333
```

Every single line has nothing but `Iris-setosa` for the labels, and the accuracy is 0.9333333.

I tried stepping through this with a debugger, and *every* item is being counted as being correct by the `if` statement (but the correctness percentage is still shown as 0.93333333).

So basically:

- It is showing that every result is "correct" (when it clearly isn't).
- It's showing `Iris-setosa` for every value
- My percentage showing as 93%. The correct value is actually approximately 94%, but I'd expect this to show 100% given that every result is supposedly "correct."

Can someone help me see what I'm missing here?

And before anyone asks, for the record, yes, I did try stepping through this with a debugger :) Also for the record, yes, this is homework.

Comment: Bad news: `np.apply_along_axis` is still a loopy function.

Comment: @coldspeed I suppose so... although it's still probably better than using an explicit `for` loop. I feel like there's probably a much better way to do this that I'm missing, though - I'm still struggling to think of it in terms other than just "translating" the `for` loop.

Comment: Did you *shuffle* your data before splitting them to training & test subsets? It seems your test set is made up from a disproportionally high number of `setosa` samples...

Comment: @desertnaut I just included a subset of the data in the question for brevity, so the full data set isn't that biased. In terms of the data itself, I was given the samples for the assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do it in one line, here is what you can do (I downloaded the dataset from scikit-learn):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Load dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
# Split training and test set
Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
# 1-neareast neighbour    
ypred = np.array([ytrain[np.argmin(np.sum((x-Xtrain)**2,axis=1))] for x in Xtest])
# Compute classification error
sum(ypred != ytest)/ len(ytest)
```

Now, this is 1-nearest neighbour, it only looks at the closest point from training set. For k-nearest neighbour, you have to change it to this:

```
# k-neareast neighbour    
k = 3
ypredk = np.array([np.argmax(np.bincount(ytrain[np.argsort(np.sum((x-Xtrain)**2,axis=1))[0:k]])) for x in Xtest])
sum(ypredk != ytest)/ len(ytest)
```

To put it in words, you sort the distances, you find the indices of the k lowest values (that's the `np.argsort` part) and the corresponding labels, then you look for the most common label among the k ones (that's the `np.argmax(np.bincount(x))` part).

Finally, if you want to make sure, you can compare with `scikit-learn`:

```
# scikit-learn NN
from sklearn import neighbors
knn = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k, algorithm='ball_tree')
knn.fit(Xtrain,ytrain)
ypred_sklearn = knn.predict(Xtest)
sum(ypred_sklearn != ytest)/ len(ytest)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Welcome to the site by the way - good to have you.